# File version different between Azure Portal and Azure Portal Kudu for the same file

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, kudu, azure-function-app

Currently my Azure Function shows a different file version in the portal as compared to Kudu.

I am using Azure App Service /w Azure Functions V2 and Python 3.7.

I publish my function app using:

```
func azure functionapp publish <functionappname>
```

It successfully performs a remote build.
Now if I look at my Function App in the portal I can see the updated version of my **init**.py. However, when I use Kudu (Platform features > Advanced tools (Kudu)) to look into the file /home/site/wwwroot//**init**.py I still see the old version. Shouldn't these versions be identical?

I hope some experienced user can shed light on this.

Comment: Hi lammy, may I know if your the answer can explain your question ? If it helps your question, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Comment: Hello Hury. Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I am checking your answer, but I am afraid i am still confused by what I am seeing. Why am not seeing the latest version of my deployment in Kudu? If I use WebSSH for the same directory, I can see my latest deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I test it in my side, when I create a new azure function app(python) and deploy the python code from VS Code to azure portal. It will not create a "init.py" under the directory `/home/site/wwwroot`. In this directory, it just exists a "host.json"(shown as below).

[image]

So you can see the new version of your "init.py" after your deployment on azure portal, but it seems the old version "init.py" in the directory `/home/site/wwwroot` may be created by a deployment in the past or created because some other reasons in the past. I think it has nothing to do with your new deployment.